# SwiftUI Map Display Annotations

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode12, ios14

I decided to switch from wrapping MKMapView into a UIViewRepresentable to the new `Map()` in SwiftUI.

I was able to display correctly a `MKMapRect` into the `Map()` but I am unable to display two `MKPointAnnotation` there. Also my route between these annotation is not showing

It is requiring me to provide an `RandomAccessCollection` and a `(Identifiable) -> MapAnnotationProtocol>` but I do not know what to put there.

Any idea what should I put in `(Identifiable) -> MapAnnotationProtocol` ?

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

extension MKPointAnnotation: Identifiable { }

struct ItemView: View {
    @ObservedObject var itemViewModel: ItemViewModel
    @State var coll = [MKPointAnnotation]()
    
    func onAppear() {
        let requestAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        requestAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 46.2004781, longitude: 6.1346497)
        requestAnnotation.title = "Package"
        
        let destinationAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        destinationAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 47.1420446, longitude: 9.5204032)
        destinationAnnotation.title = "Destination"
        
        coll.append(requestAnnotation)
        coll.append(destinationAnnotation)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let mapRect = itemViewModel.route?.polyline.boundingMapRect {
                Map(mapRect: .constant(mapRect), annotationItems: coll) { point in
                  MapAnnotation(coordinate: point.coordinate) {
                      Text(point.title ?? "")
                  }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: self.onAppear)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do `MKPointAnnotation` anymore. Currently, in Xcode 12.0 Beta, there are three structs that SwiftUI provides to satisfy the `MapAnnotationProtocol`:

- `MapAnnotation`
- `MapMarker`
- `MapPin`

The `RandomAccessCollection` should be any collection (an array will do) of objects that adopt `Identifiable`. These used as the argument of the block in the final argument of the `Map` initializer.

```
Map(coordinateRegion: $container.region, 
    annotationItems: container.annotationLocations) { 
        (location) -> MapPin in
            MapPin(coordinate: location.coordinate)
    })
```

Comment: What about a Route? Is it possible to do it in SwiftUI or not yet ?

Comment: I don't know. Was hoping they'd publish a video about the new map features, but I guess we didn't get that yet. We'll see if it gets fleshed out in the next few betas...

Comment: Can you do an example with MapAnnotation. I need also to display some text thats why I need MapAnnotation

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that `MapAnnotation` requires you to implement the whole view that will be rendered on the map, so if you want both the red pin and some text, you will have to create that pin yourself (e.g. as an instance of Image with SF Symbol). Of course it doesn't look as good as the pin from `MapMarker` but at least it's a start.

```
Map(coordinateRegion: .constant(mapRect), annotationItems: coll) { annotationItem in
  MapAnnotation(coordinate: annotationItem.coordinate) {
    VStack {
      Group {
        Image(systemName: "mappin.circle.fill")
          .resizable()
          .frame(width: 30.0, height: 30.0)
        Circle()
          .frame(width: 8.0, height: 8.0)
      }
      .foregroundColor(.red)
      Text(annotationItem.title)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be like the following (not tested due to absent dependencies in provided snapshot)

```
Map(mapRect: .constant(mapRect), annotationItems: coll) { point in
   MapAnnotation(coordinate: point.coordinate) {
    Text(point.title ?? "")
   }
}
```

Comment: code compiles fine but I can not see the red annotations, idea what i'm still doing wrong here?

Comment: also I updated my question with hard coded coordinates for testing.